# Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA ignoring ValidationMessages.properties (test project included)

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA not looking up custom validation messages in the property file ValidationMessages.properties.

To illustrate the problem, I created a small example project, which you can get through git:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/sstein/validation-example.git
```

After you got the source tree, you can test the problem by running the unit tests I created using:

```
mvn test
```

There are 3 test cases and validateDescriptionTest(com.example.MyClassTest) is failing with:

> expected:<[Description must be between 1 and 10 characters long.]> but was:<[{descriptionMsg}]>

I also added a test case verifying that the resource bundle is accessible by unit tests and this works.

Does anyone know why this one is failing?

PS: I completely rewrote my initial question adding the example so that you can try on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is simple and was [found by Hardy Ferentschik of Hibernate](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1016107):

In Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA, the bundle must be called **ValidatorMessages.properties** and NOT **ValidationMessages.properties**.

Comment: Thanks, in the jersey example it has the older name, so I was tripped up. https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp

Answer (score 2):

The final location of ValidationMessages.properties shuold be in WEB-INF/classes. How it gets there depends on the build system you are using and how you configure it. In NetBeans IDE, when I create a web application, I can just put ValidationMessages.properties into the default Java package.

In case you are using Maven as a build tool, put the properties into the /src/main/resources directory, this way Maven will copy it into WEB-INF/classes.

To make sure that the properties file is in place, open the .war file as a ZIP and just take a look. Another way to tell is just by checking if JSF picks up the validator messages inside.

For JSR-303 messages like @Size, the above properties key should be correct.

Comment: I rewrote my question adding a small example project. If you like, you can test it yourself. Messages don't get resolved by the resource bundle even though ValidationMessages.properties can be found in target/classes after running "mvn test".